# Video saving in MP4

Tags: rendering, video

I downloaded the Blender version 2.82 to edit videos.

I opened an .mp4 file to start cutting scenes out of it but when I saved it, it showed .blend file and I cannot find a way to render it because its different than any videos I found on the internet. Please give me a detailed step by step instruction as i dont need it for anything else but this?

Thank You

Comment: "Please give me a detailed step by step instruction"
First, you give us a detailed description what you have done, to not force anybody to guess.
Reasonable questions:
- "when I saved it"  -- save as what, precisely. Describe file format you "saved".
- "it showed .blend file"  -- who showed?
- "I cannot find a way to render" -- did you try to look into main menu?

Answer (score 2):

You have to render your video, setting dimensions, frame rate, file destination, codecs and related settings, like in example, then choose "Render animation" (Ctrl F12).

[image]